# Creating z-aware Shapefile with QGis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, 3d

Is there a way to create a z-aware Shapefile directly in QGis?

It seems the support for z-coordinates in QGis has been building up over the last years (which is why similar questions in the past are not very helpful). However it seems 3D Shapefiles cannot be created directly in QGis.

I am using QGis 2.18.10 and cannot find the option to create a Shapefile with z-Coordinates. I have not been using QGis for long, but it seems odd that there is no option in the "New Shapefile Layer" dialog.

A possible workaround to this is creating a 2D-Shape and save it using the geometry > include z-Dimension. Is there another way?

Comment: I don't see how anyone who read both questions (not just the title) can consider this a duplicate. You suggest to create an empty Shapefile in QGis I do not only need a (2D) Shapefile, but also a raster? I was asking for a "direct" way.